# How do I have the program run in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a program which will record the currently playing song, but I want the app to run in the background, so when the user is in a different app or when the device is locked and my app is in the background and they go to the next song, the program will know. Currently I can take the current playing song and put it into parse when the app is open.

```
     func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    print("entered background")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
}

func getNowPlayingItem() {
    if  let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem  {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
        let artisttest = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
        if let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String{

            let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")
            let object = PFObject(className: "MasterSongs")

            //    print("Artist: " + artist)


            let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                    self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

                    // print(self.Parsearray)
                }


                if self.Parsearray.contains(title!){
                    print("already in db")
                }else{
                    objectPointer["title"] = title
                    objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    objectPointer["artist"] = artist
                    objectPointer.saveInBackground()


                }

            })




        }else{
            let object = PFObject(className: "MasterSongs")
            object.setObject(title!, forKey: "title")
            //object.setObject(artist!, forKey: "artist")
            object.saveInBackground()

            let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")


            let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                    self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

                    // print(self.Parsearray)
                }


                if self.Parsearray.contains(title!){
                    print("already in db")
                }else{
                    objectPointer["title"] = title
                    objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    objectPointer["artist"] = "No artist found :("
                    objectPointer.saveInBackground()


                }

            })





        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple support some of the background mode. If you are using any Apple framework for audio play then select your App target and go in `Capabilites` options and enable background mode and choose the appropriate options.

Check the screenshot.[image]

Comment: So I think I know what is wrong, I am calling the function in the view will appear and since the app will be running in the background the viewWillAppear will not be called unless the app is opened, will your method fix this?

Comment: Just enable the background mode as mentioned in answer and then test your code.

Comment: No it does not work. I also added it to the plist http://puu.sh/lGm9b/3459d6f072.png

Comment: Go through this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html

Comment: Here is a tutorial regarding background audio play, also it has links to Background Task http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-multitasking-background-audio--mobile-6833

Comment: I don't need audio to be played in the background. Instead I need my program to capture the data of the music being played in the ios native music app. It can currently do that when the app is open, but not when it is running in the background.

Comment: If your audio won't play in background then how would you capture the data on the first place. If audio is kept playing then you can place your data capturing code within UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier block so it will keep  calling in background. But it has limitation, it won't allow longer task in background. Here is the link to how can you still run a certain piece of code in background. You need to do any of the background mode option. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-multitasking-background-tasks--mobile-6913

Comment: Just to clarify, my app does not play audio. The user plays music using the itunes app, then I just record the title and artist. I want to be able to record that even when the app is in the background and the user is still listening to music.

Comment: Okay for that go through the link that allows particular piece of code to run in background.Give it a try.

Comment: So I went ahead and used the entered background function in the appdelegate, and I am getting the printed line entered background to indicate it is running in the background, but the function getNowPlayingItem is not being called.

Comment: I gave it a try , i followed the same approach and i write a small print function in my AppDelegate and call it when apps enter in background and it did called. There is something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: Am I calling the getNowPlayingItem in the applicationDidEnterBackground function?

Comment: Yes of course, you need to call that method in that block, just after the print line running in background. so the system will know which method to call in background.

Comment: Since you are working on swift , here is a background tutorial for swift, it has sample code too, so you can map stuff if you miss something. http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial